# NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID security certificate does not specify Subject Alternative Names

Tags: windows, ssl, active-directory, ssl-certificate, iis-8

I apologize if my english is not too good. I am trying to create a certificate request from my IIS server, but everytime i completed the request. The client still don't trust the web server.

I am from a development background not really into infrastructure operation. So my question might be incorrect, due to misconception, if so, please feel free to educate me. Below are my questions:

Do I need to import the root certificate into the window IIS server before starting a certificate request? If so, how do i create or export a root certificate from Window Certificate Authority?

Comment: I fixed this issue adding subject alternative names during server certificate creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error can be because of multiple reasons

a) You are using an IP address to access the website (assuming you have a certificate based on a URL). So try accessing using the URL for which you have procured the certificate

b) You have procured certificate for xyz.com but have binded the same to abc.com . Hence when accessing abc.com you receive the above error. Bind the correct certificate  if have one.

c) YOu have procured a multi domain certificate , but the url you are trying to access is not added as SAN to the certificate. Have a word with your SSL provider and ask him to add the URL as SAN to the certificate.

Answer (score 2):

*Although this answer is not Windows-specific, I found this page through a search for my problem, and hopefully the following information will be of use to someone having this problem on Linux, like me:*

I have encountered this problem too and, although the accepted answer is probably correct, the process for generating a CSR (certificate signing request) with the SAN (Subject Alternative Name) requires a bit of explanation.

There are several articles detailing this, but basically, you need to create a file, let's call it `ssl.conf`, which contains the necessary information, including the SAN details, which you will pass via a parameter to the `openssl` command when creating the CSR.

(This assumes you have already generated a key).

The contents of `ssl.conf` can be as simple as follows. Note the section at the bottom detailing the SAN. **Adjust all the parameters to suit your requirements.**

```
[req]
default_bits = 2048
prompt = no
default_md = sha256
req_extensions = req_ext
distinguished_name = dn

[ dn ]
C=US
ST=New York
L=Rochester
O=End Point
OU=Testing Domain
emailAddress=your-administrative-address@your-awesome-existing-domain.com
CN = www.your-new-domain.com

[ req_ext ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names

[ alt_names ]
DNS.1 = your-new-domain.com
DNS.2 = www.your-new-domain.com
```

The rest of the file contains other X.509 information that you would be prompted for during the CSR creation (country, state etc.)

Now you can create your CSR as follows:

```
openssl req -new -sha256 -out private.csr -key private.key -config ssl.conf
```

Where `private.csr` refers to your new CSR file, `private.key` refers to the key you already should have generated and `ssl.conf` is the file above.

You can verify the contents of your new CSR as follows:

```
openssl req -text -noout -verify -in private.csr
```

Then you will see, on the console, the details of the CSR, including the SAN details.

References:

- https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2014/10/30/openssl-csr-with-alternative-names-one
- https://gist.github.com/croxton/ebfb5f3ac143cd86542788f972434c96
- https://geekflare.com/san-ssl-certificate/

Answer (score 0):

Should not the answer be that Subject Alternative Name (SAN) is mandated by Chrome for Certificate Validation check? Here is a [link](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=381) which speaks more about comparison between Common Name (CN) and SAN